# t-sql group by pivot query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, pivot

I have a result set

```
name        time_begin      time_end
SUNDAY      00:01:00        13:59:00
SUNDAY      14:01:00        23:59:00
MONDAY      22:01:00        21:59:00
TUESDAY     00:01:00        23:59:00
WEDNESDAY   00:01:00        23:59:00
THURSDAY    00:01:00        23:59:00
FRIDAY      00:01:00        23:59:00
SATURDAY    00:01:00        23:59:00
```

now I want this data to be shown as

```
SUNDAY_begin    SUNDAY_end      MONDAY_begin    MONDAY_end  TUESDAY_begin   TUESDAY_end
00:01:00        13:59:00        22:01:00        21:59:00    00:01:00        23:59:00
14:01:00        23:59:00        null            null        null            null
```

and so on for other days.

how could I achieve this in t-sql query?

UPDATE:
-> @Deepak's query: yes. since there are initially two rows in sunday, so the second row in the new resultset. since there are no multiple rows for Monday or Tuesday, it is null. there is no logical grouping. Imagine its just a list of possible time slots for any day.
Thanks.

Comment: The title of your question shows you know what you need to do, have you tried, if so edit your question to include what you've got so far.

Comment: Its just a guess. I am not sure though.

Comment: how do you distinguish two rows ? because there are two `sunday` and the combination may differ, for example : in your expected output the nulls are in first row and values are in second row... what is the logic behind the expected result? please elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get a column for `ROW_NUMBER()` to get rows for repeated values in each weekdays.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) RNO,
    NAME+'_begin' [DATECOL],time_begin
    FROM yourtable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) RNO,
    NAME+'_end',time_end
    FROM yourtable
)
SELECT 
MIN(CASE WHEN [DATECOL]='SUNDAY_begin' THEN time_begin END)SUNDAY_begin,
MIN(CASE WHEN [DATECOL]='SUNDAY_end' THEN time_begin END)SUNDAY_begin,
MIN(CASE WHEN [DATECOL]='MONDAY_begin' THEN time_begin END)MONDAY_begin,
MIN(CASE WHEN [DATECOL]='MONDAY_end' THEN time_begin END)MONDAY_end,
MIN(CASE WHEN [DATECOL]='TUESDAY_begin' THEN time_begin END)TUESDAY_begin,
MIN(CASE WHEN [DATECOL]='TUESDAY_end' THEN time_begin END)TUESDAY_end,
MIN(CASE WHEN [DATECOL]='WEDNESDAY_begin' THEN time_begin END)WEDNESDAY_begin,
MIN(CASE WHEN [DATECOL]='WEDNESDAY_end' THEN time_begin END)WEDNESDAY_end,
MIN(CASE WHEN [DATECOL]='THURSDAY_begin' THEN time_begin END)THURSDAY_begin,
MIN(CASE WHEN [DATECOL]='THURSDAY_end' THEN time_begin END)THURSDAY_end,
MIN(CASE WHEN [DATECOL]='FRIDAY_begin' THEN time_begin END)FRIDAY_begin,
MIN(CASE WHEN [DATECOL]='FRIDAY_end' THEN time_begin END)FRIDAY_end,
MIN(CASE WHEN [DATECOL]='SATURDAY_begin' THEN time_begin END)SATURDAY_begin,
MIN(CASE WHEN [DATECOL]='SATURDAY_end' THEN time_begin END)SATURDAY_end
FROM CTE
GROUP BY RNO
```

**RESULT**

Since SQL Fiddle has internal errors, I am adding result image.

[image]

Comment: I think this is exactly what I needed. Just checking now. Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome :) @Tiju John

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the results you are looking for:

```
Select t1.Sunday Sunday_Begin, t2.Sunday Sunday_End, t1.Monday Monday_Begin, t2.Monday Monday_End, t1.Tuesday Tuesday_Begin, t2.Tuesday Tuesday_End, t1.Wednesday Wednesday_Begin, t2.Wednesday Wednesday_End, t1.Thursday Thursday_Begin, t2.Thursday Thursday_End, t1.Friday Friday_Begin, t2.Friday Friday_End, t1.Saturday Saturday_Begin, t2.Saturday Saturday_End

From

(Select RNo, Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday
from
(Select ROW_NUMBER() Over(Partition by name order by time_begin) RNo, name, time_begin
from #tbl) tb1
pivot
(min(time_begin) for name in (Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday)) as pv1) as t1

JOIN

(Select RNo, Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday
from
(Select ROW_NUMBER() Over(Partition by Name order by time_begin) RNo, name, time_end
from #tbl) tb2
pivot
(min(time_end) for name in (Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday)) as pv1) as t2 on t1.RNo = t2.RNo
```